# Can not load file or assembly System.Web.Http

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, umbraco7

I have instaled Umbraco 7.2.8, I save content but I have the error :

> Can not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version = 4.0.0.0,
>   Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. It was expected that the module has an assembly
>   manifest.

How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to install the .net framework 4.0 runtime.

Comment: Thanks Bilpor, this error is only in one project, in other projects don't have errors. If I reinstall the .net ramework it not afect other projects?

Comment: it should not effect other projects. The runtimes can live side by side. I'm assuming that if other projects work they are either using later versions of .NET or do not use the System.Web.Http namespace.

Comment: I reinstall the .net framework but the error is the same, is possible reinstall the assembly?

Comment: I can solve this error. I create new install of Umbraco (same version) and copy folders of images, media, css, scripts, views and config, restart the project and ready!!!